# dyld: Library not loaded: libabc.dylib Image not found

Tags: xcode, macos

I am building an application for MacOSX 10.13 in Xcode 13.2.1.  I am trying to include libabc.dylib as an external library.  The application compiles fine but when it goes to run, it gets the following error:

```
  Referenced from: /Users/path/in/DerivedData/thing.app/Contents/MacOS/thing
  Reason: image not found
```

I currently have it included in `Frameworks,Libraries, and Embedded Content` within `General` settings.  I also have tried adding the library under `Copy Files` within `Build Phases`.

Running `otool -L libabc.dylib` results in:
`@loader_path/libabc.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)`

I've add `@loader_path/` to my `Runpath Search Paths` under `Linking` in the `Build Settings` menu.  I'm completely stumped and none of the answers out there are working to get rid of this error.

Comment: should be an `/../Frameworks` after `@loader_path` to have it point to its directory...

Comment: Assuming this is the ```Runpath Search Path``` you are referring to, adding that makes no difference.

Comment: `@loader_path` encodes the dir of the binary calling the load function.  So your dyld library must be located relative to `@loader_path`.

Comment: The ```otool -L libabc.dylib``` of the lib where it is in the directories shows up as ```@loader_path/libabc.dylib``` but the one showing in the referenced path (/Users/.../DerivedData/.../thing) is ```libabc.dylib``` without anything in front of it.  How can I fix this descrepancy?

Comment: Depending on the locations: `install_name_tool -change libabc.dylib @loader_path/../Frameworks/libabc.dylib  ~/DerivedData/.../thing` but that is by command line and not necessarily the Xcode setting you may need.